# How to make a simple non-blocking popup window in a console C++ program?

Tags: c++, qt, gtk, wxwidgets

I try to figure out in which C++ GUI toolkit (+stdlib+libc) it would be easiest to implement such a useful function in a normal command-line application:

```
void ShowStringWindow(string& s) {
  // ...
}
```

ShowStringWindow should display a window with an editable box containing string s.
It should return immediately, so the main thread can continue.

Notes:

- If the main thread changes the string the displayed, string should change as well. (active checking is fine)
- If a user edits the string (and confirms with enter) the string s should be updated.
- You can assume that the main thread will not read or write to this string at the time of the update.
- Next calls to ShowStringWindow add more similar windows (or more widgets to existing window if that is not-too-difficult to implement).
- It should work on linux/ubuntu.

I would be very grateful for a working code, but that is not necessary to be useful.

Comment: Are you making a console app or a windows app? You've tagged Qt, wxWidgets, etc but there is no mention of which framework you are implementing under in the question if any of these ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=modeless+dialog

Comment: @AJG85: It is explicitely written that it is console app both in title and contents.

Comment: @Lukasz Sorry I meant to emphasize console programs are by nature command line driven or use text based terminals. Popup windows, modeless dialogs, edit controls, widgets, and the kinds of things you seem to want aren't.

Comment: Does your windowing framework allow creating a simple dialog in another thread?  If it does, this seems the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with Qt, you need to:

- Create a mutex for the string
  variable.
- Create a thread, obviously.
- Create a QApplication object, in that
  thread. (on the first call)
- Set the "setQuitOnLastWindowsClosed"
  to false on the QApplication. (on the first call)
- Create the dialog and "exec" it.

After the "exec" function returns, you need to:

- Delete the dialog object
- Call
  QApplication::instance()->quit();
- Delete the QApplication object.
- End the thread.

There are a few ways you can update data from the main thread.
One way would be to use signals/slots with queued connection type. Using this, the UI thread updates the value. Easing the impact on the main thread. However, note that if the value update rate is too high, like 2000 times per second, you might want to change to polling the value. To do that, you might find QTimer helpful.

Updating data to the main thread should be somewhat easier, just lock the mutex and insert the value. At this point, you could check if the value that we previously got from the main thread is still the current value in the main thread. You did state that it doesn't change, but i'd not trust that :)

I hope this is sufficient. We used this to create a Qt based error dialog for a console program.

Comment: I don't know if this is the case, but if you try to run the event loop of the QThread before there is a QApplication, it won't work. This is because an event loop cannot be created unless there is an instance of QCoreApplication (inherited by QApplication). If this is the case, you can fix it by overriding the "run" function from QThread and creating the QApplication there. This will work because the QThread hasn't attempted to run it's event loop, yet. When "run" returns, it will.